# How is the Shia prostration of thanksgiving performed?

Tags: shiism, sujud

One thing I noticed when praying in Iran is that many people perform an extra sujud (prostration) directly after the (Shia-style) [taslim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taslim).  It didn't seem obligatory as not everyone did it, but it seemed common practice.  It looks like this is a *prostration of thanksgiving* ([ref.](http://www.duas.org/sajdashukr.htm)) which I had not encountered before going to Iran.

I would like to know precisely how this is performed in case I decide to do this too.

**Question**: How is the Shia prostration of thanksgiving performed?

There appears to be differences, e.g., one does not perform the other parts of the [rakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakat), but go straight into sujud from the sitting position.

Answer (score 1):

1. Imam was riding a horse and suddenly he stopped and went onto sujjud. His followers asked: Oh son of RasullAllah. Why did you suddenly do sujjud?

   Imam: I just remembered a certain blessing of Allah and did sujjud.
2. Thanksgiving is recommended at all times. The most recommended are to physically prostrate, and if you can't do that then place your hand on your forehead and if you can't do that then just say it in your heart.

I'll have to find the references of the above narrations and make an edit, but basically it's just recommended to prostrate for anything and everything at all times. After your praying is just one of those times.
It's recommended to say *الحمد الله* and then ask for anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

How is the prostration of Shiite sugar performed?
The prostration of sugar is recommended in the following cases: after each obligatory and recommended prayer; When a new blessing arrives or a blessing is renewed; When remorse and calamity are removed from human beings and also reminding them; After succeeding in doing a good deed or leaving a sin, as well as when observing a person suffering from a calamity and seeing a sinner.
The prostration of sugar is achieved by performing prostration. Therefore, prostration of sugar does not have Takbir opening, Takbir when going to prostration, as well as tashahhud and salaam; The prostration of sugar is accomplished by prostrating once. In prostration, facing the Qibla is not a condition.

Ref: https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%87_%D8%B4%DA%A9%D8%B1